# Why my website icon is not displaying in search engines?

Tags: html, favicon, google-search

I'm hosting my website online and my HTML page contains the following:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}website_pictures/picture.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

However, for the last 2 weeks the icon doesn't show up next to my website on Google, although it appears on the tab once I click my website. I've used Google Search Console to submit my sitemap and it seems that my pages are being indexed without any errors.

```html
<link rel="icon" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}website_pictures/picture.ico?" type="image/x-icon">
```

I've tried appending `?` to the URL but this doesn't work either. The media URL is from an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

> #### Define a favicon to show in search results
>
> Your favicon must be a multiple of 48px square, for example: 48x48px,
> 96x96px, 144x144px and so on.

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search